# How do I properly dispose the byte array used in the class?

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, memory-leaks

I have a StateObject class which is being used to store the data from client and server.

Here is the code:

```
 public class StateObject : IDisposable 
    {
        public StateObject()
        {

        }

        public String serviceName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ServiceName"].ToString().Trim();  //Holds the service name 
        public Socket clientSocket; //socket for communication with the client

        public int id; //client id  (A running sequence to keep track of StateObjects)

        public string leaseId; //holds the leaseId that is used to communicate with the server

        public bool isLeaseIdValid = false;

        public string requestQuery = string.Empty;

        public IPEndPoint serverEP;

        public Socket serverSocket; //Socket for communication with the server

        public static int BUFFER_SIZE = Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BufferSize"].ToString().Trim());  //Get the buffer size from the state object

        public byte[] clientReadBuffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];   // Receive clientReadBuffer.
        public byte[] serverReadBuffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];

        public int clientNumBytes;
        public byte[] clientSendBuffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
        public int serverNumBytes;
        public byte[] serverSendBuffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];

        public bool isShutdown = false;

        public Socket serverSocketPort80; //Socket for communication with the server

        public bool ConnectedToPort80 = false; //initially set to false

        public ConnectionObject connectionObject;

        #region Dispose implementation

        public void Dispose()
        {
            Dispose(true);
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }

        protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                connectionObject.Dispose();
            }
        }

        ~StateObject()
        {
            Dispose(false);
        }

        #endregion
    }
```

How do I properly dispose this class and clearup the memory used by the byte array ? The byte arrays are being used to store sent/received messages in a socket communication.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You only need to dispose unmanaged memory.

In this case it looks like the only thing you need to dispose is the `Socket` and possibly the `ConnectionObject`, whatever that is.

In other words, dispose any instances of `IDisposable` that this class creates.

The garbage collector will take care of the byte arrays once this object falls out of scope.

Comment: Additionally, this class is not actually assigning a `Socket` reference, so this class doesn't need a Dispose or Destructor.

Comment: @Tejs, right, the code doesn't show quite where the socket comes from. If it's passed in from outside, then it shouldn't be being disposed here.

Comment: @DrewNoakes what if i cant w8 for the GC, or the byte array is really long (2GB long)?!? i need that gone asap!!!

Comment: @Leonardo, the byte array is managed. If you've removed all references to it you can call [`GC.Collect()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xe0c2357(v=vs.110).aspx), though it's not guaranteed to perform a collection. From .NET 4.5.1 you can also request compaction of the large object heap by setting `GCSettings.LargeObjectHeapCompactionMode = GCLargeObjectHeapCompactionMode.CompactOnce` before calling `Collect`.

Answer (score 5):

You don't (as described in @DrewNoakes answer). If you identify this particular section of code as an object creation/memory allocation hotspot, consider creating a pool of byte arrays from which you can lease an already allocated array. Generally I try to do this with server software so there's some sort of upper bound on memory usage.