# Transferring datagridview data to excel

Tags: excel, vb.net, winforms, datagridview, epplus

I'm transferring my datagridview data to an excel file using EPPlus, my problem is the process is eating memory, what am I missing to free up the used memory? on the outside it seems fine with a few thousand rows but the memory used by the program rises and doesn't go back down after exporting and saving to excel. Now when I try to export a million rows I run out of memory.

Here's my code, this process runs on a background worker.

```
Using p = New ExcelPackage
        Dim sheetnum As Integer = 2
        Dim ws As ExcelWorksheet = CreateSheet(p, "report")
        For Each dgcol As DataGridViewColumn In dg.Columns
            ws.Cells(1, col).Value = dgcol.HeaderText
            col += 1
        Next

        For Each rowx As DataGridViewRow In dg.Rows
            For Each colx As DataGridViewColumn In dg.Columns
                ws.Cells(row, colx.Index + 1).Value = dg.Rows(rowx.Index).Cells(colx.Index).Value
            Next
            row += 1
            BackgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(CInt(100 * Integer.Parse(rowx.Index + 1) / dg.Rows.Count), CInt(100 * Integer.Parse(rowx.Index + 1) / dg.Rows.Count))
            If row = 1048577 Then 'Check if max rows have been reached and create a new sheet
                ws = CreateSheet(p, "report" & sheetnum)
                sheetnum += 1
                row = 2
                col = 1
                For Each dgcol As DataGridViewColumn In dg.Columns
                    ws.Cells(1, col).Value = dgcol.HeaderText
                    col += 1
                Next
            End If
        Next

        Dim bin() As Byte = p.GetAsByteArray()
        File.WriteAllBytes(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) & "\" & "report.xlsx", bin)
    End Using
```

Comment: You need to dispose [`ExcelWorksheet`](https://epplus.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#EPPlus/ExcelWorksheet.cs) after you finished working with it.

Comment: @RezaAghaei Thanks for the suggestion but that didn't work.

Comment: I'm not sure if it solve the whole problem, but if you take a look at implementation of the `Dispose` method for the `ExcelWorksheet` class, you will see the code releases many resources and probably the author of code knows better than us which that some resources needs to be released.

Comment: @RezaAghaei I don't know how much it should have helped but it did something but not much as I was expecting, I tried exporting around 13000 rows, my program was using around 40mb of memory, when I started the export process it jumped to 75mb, without the dispose command it stayed there, with the dispose command it went down to 68-70mb, I was expecting it to just go back to around 40mb. Anyway this still won't give me a solution to running out of memory if I export a million rows. Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at some links about EPPlus memory usage like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26787443/epplus-large-dataset-issue-with-out-of-memory-exception).

Answer (score 0):

Since it's encased in a `using` block, the `ExcelPackage` object is properly disposed of. You said that you have also disposed of the `ExcelWorksheet` object in the comments and that did not work out.

However, i think that you are not disposing the byte array that you write to file in the last line of code (before the `End Using`)

Try that. Hope it helps.

Comment: There is no `.dispose` for byte

Comment: Please read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13033684/how-do-i-properly-dispose-the-byte-array-used-in-the-class - basically, you can just call the garbage collector and ask to collect